# Format of original_application_version in iOS receipt

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I am wondering what the format of the `original_application_version` in an app-receipt that we get back from Apples `https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt` is? My testflight versions always returned "1.0" so I'd expected it to be in the format I enter in my info.plist. But now it seems that those number are something totally different.
F.e. instead of the value being "2.6" for a user of my app it return "14".
How am I able to figure out that the real version was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out... the number is the build number. Pretty Useless-Information if you ask me, as you can start all over again a 0 if you have a new app version... but that's how it is...